# header-wrapper background image not loading in Blogger post

Tags: html, css

My blog hosted at blogger http://development-platform.blogspot.sg is loading with header-wrapper image "[back.jpg](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0lbeIzTG3Nc/WT7DAREUYxI/AAAAAAAAC54/4sv9zQWVr0E_Lh50GWoVK2gWMBYwAYIfwCLcB/s1600/back.jpg)"  but when I click on the blog [post](http://development-platform.blogspot.sg/2018/05/masai-mara.html?m=0) my header-wrapper image "[back.jpg](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0lbeIzTG3Nc/WT7DAREUYxI/AAAAAAAAC54/4sv9zQWVr0E_Lh50GWoVK2gWMBYwAYIfwCLcB/s1600/back.jpg)" is not loading.

Thanks in advance.

Chrome debugger show the "background: url" line is strikeout on the blog [post](http://development-platform.blogspot.sg/2018/05/masai-mara.html?m=0) attached the image of the Chrome debugger [Chrome debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH8ka.jpg)

```css
#header-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0lbeIzTG3Nc/WT7DAREUYxI/AAAAAAAAC54/4sv9zQWVr0E_Lh50GWoVK2gWMBYwAYIfwCLcB/s1600/back.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you have some CSS overriding this one .. try adding `!important`

Comment: thx. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a specificity issue. The `background: #fff` in `.item #head-wrapper` is more specific than the background set in `#head-wrapper`.

Yes you could use `!important` to work around it, but I would suggest refactoring the existing css to be more correct.

Go back into the chrome dev tool and uncheck the `background: #fff` to see the result.